# Passing a struct as P thread argument Linux cannot convert to a pointer type

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, linux-device-driver

```
// this is my struct ///

typedef struct
{
HCORE BM_cores[0];
int total_cores;
} BM_PARAMS;

BM_PARAMS BM_Dat;
```

Im trying to pass this struct to a pthread

```
int Start_monitor(void)
{
int RETVAL=0;
 RETVAL = pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, Get_Monitor_Data,(void*)BM_Dat);
 if(RETVAL !=0)
 {
  printf("Error Starting Thread \n");
 }

 return 0;
 }
```

**at Pthreadcreate, im getting a error .. cannot convert to pointer type**

```
void *Get_Monitor_Data (void *BM_Dat) // Bus Monitor Thread
{
BM_PARAMS*monitor_params;
int no_of_cores=0;
monitor_params = (BM_PARAMS *) BM_Dat;

BTICard_CardReset(*monitor_params->BM_cores);// reset card if required

return 0;
}
```

im getting an error of  cannot convert to pointer type
im using eclipse for coding

Comment: Can you post the exact error? The error might tell you what variable specifically can't be converted to pointer type.

Comment: Note: although typically pronounced like "pea thread", as if the "p" were a separate initial, "pthread" is in fact one word.

Answer (score 0):

This ...

> ```
> typedef struct
> {
> HCORE BM_cores[0];
> int total_cores;
> } BM_PARAMS;
>
> BM_PARAMS BM_Dat;
> ```

... declares variable `BM_Dat` to have type `BM_PARAMS`, which is a structure type.  There's nothing wrong with that.

This excerpt of your thread function ...

> ```
> void *Get_Monitor_Data (void *BM_Dat) // Bus Monitor Thread
> {
> BM_PARAMS*monitor_params;
> int no_of_cores=0;
> monitor_params = (BM_PARAMS *) BM_Dat;
> ```

... shows that it expects its argument to be a *pointer to* a `BM_PARAMS`.  There's nothing wrong with that, either.

But this call to `pthread_create()` ...

> ```
>  RETVAL = pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, Get_Monitor_Data,(void*)BM_Dat);
> ```

... is attempting to convert `BM_Dat` to a pointer, which is not meaningful or possible.  What you appear to want to do instead is pass the *address* of variable `BM_dat`.  That is, you want this:

```
 RETVAL = pthread_create(&monitor_thread, NULL, Get_Monitor_Data, &BM_Dat);
```

It is not necessary to cast `&BM_Dat` to type `void *` as all object pointers can automatically be converted to type `void *` (and back) without one.  More generally, casts for other than arithmetic purposes have bad code smell.  They are usually either unnecessary or wrong.